# bootstrap 3: Dynamically re-size a panel and keep panel footer on bottom

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm resizing a panel to be the same height as the column to its left.

[Here a bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/125859)

I resizes fine but the panels footer is stuck at the top. What is the best way to solve this?

Here's the js I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Panels have a margin-bottom
    $topRightCol = $('.homepage-top-right-col .panel');
    $leftColHeight = $('.homepage-top-left-col').height() - 
        parseInt($topRightCol.css('margin-bottom')) -
        parseInt($topRightCol.css('borderBottomWidth'));
    $topRightCol.height($leftColHeight);
```

When I tried to set the height on the column class itself like this ('.homepage-top-right-col).height($leftColHeight) it didn't increase the height so I modified the panel instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well..you could solve this with a bit of extra CSS, and `position:absolute`, if you aren't against that. I added these CSS styles:

```
.homepage-top-right-col > .panel{
    position:relative;
}
.homepage-top-right-col .panel-footer{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This causes the `.panel-footer` of the right panel to always stick to its bottom, regardless of the panel's height. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMnB8/) to show you what this achieves.

Hope this helps! If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: That kinda works, but the big panel on the right isn't exactly the same height, looks like its a bit shorter.

Comment: Make sure you expand the preview pane to full width (so it stops using mobile styles), then refresh the page. Your JavaScript currently only evaluates the height once, and with mobile styles the combined heights of the panels is a little less. If you expand the preview pane only after the page loads, the heights won't appear to match.